# Rendering collection partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

From the [Using Ajax and jQuery in Rails 5 Apps](https://rubyplus.com/articles/4211-Using-Ajax-and-jQuery-in-Rails-5-Apps) tutorial (the project can be found at [bparanj/ckl](https://github.com/bparanj/ckl)) and given the following view and partial:

app/views/tasks/index.html.erb:

```
<h1>Task Dog</h1>

<%= link_to "New Task", new_task_path, id: "new_link" %>

<h2>Incomplete Tasks</h2>
<div class="tasks" id="incomplete_tasks">
  <%= render @incomplete_tasks %>
</div>

<h2>Complete Tasks</h2>
<div class="tasks" id="complete_tasks">
  <%= render @complete_tasks %>
</div>
```

app/views/tasks/_task.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for task do |f| %>
  <%= f.check_box :complete %>
  <%= f.submit "Update" %>
  <%= f.label :complete, task.name %>
  <%= link_to "(remove)", task, method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"} %>
<% end %>
```

The problem is clicking on any element only selects the first item (shown below) which makes me think the partial is being rendered incorrectly.

Looking through the rails guide about [rendering collection](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials) I wasn't able to find the answer.

Why isn't the `<%= f.label :complete, task.name %>` line working as expected?

About to click on `baz`:

[image]

Clicking on `baz` expecting `baz` to get checked but instead `foo` gets checked (note: the actual checkbox works but not the text next to the checkbox):

[image]

Edit:

Note I'm on the commit before the author adds ajax:

```
git checkout 1bb43bd
```

After bundling and starting the server:

```
curl http://localhost:3000/tasks | pbcopy
```

Gives the following html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Ckl</title>
    <meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token" />
<meta name="csrf-token" content="xlNcxfUn9NoUFZGrmeRGaK9uNhz01F43vs0ATt9qb+XIk414hTj37YZxDo1mAm3VOT7otj/qMgB+FLVaNsn8Aw==" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/layout.self-cc3852a9caa9db7dd4f2a4f654027564a1cb5bd14f24754194e6fd3129377e24.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/tasks.self-d679d83f2b24213289ec1a5948d0d54ec9798f954c5a996908ed19a7a108c6bf.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/application.self-af04b226fd7202dfc532ce7aedb95a0128277937e90d3b3a3d35e1cce9e16886.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload" />
    <script src="/assets/jquery.self-660adc51e0224b731d29f575a6f1ec167ba08ad06ed5deca4f1e8654c135bf4c.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.self-e87806d0cf4489aeb1bb7288016024e8de67fd18db693fe026fe3907581e53cd.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/turbolinks.self-c5acd7a204f5f25ce7a1d8a0e4d92e28d34c9e2df2c7371cd7af88e147e4ad82.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/action_cable.self-1641ec3e8ea24ed63601e86efcca7f9266e09f390e82199d56aa7e4bd50e1aa9.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/cable.self-6e0514260c1aa76eaf252412ce74e63f68819fd19bf740595f592c5ba4c36537.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/tasks.self-877aef30ae1b040ab8a3aba4e3e309a11d7f2612f44dde450b5c157aa5f95c05.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/application.self-b89234cf2659d7fedea75bca0b8d231ad7dfc2f3f57fcbaf5f44ed9dc384137b.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <h1>Task Dog</h1>

<a id="new_link" href="/tasks/new">New Task</a>

<h2>Incomplete Tasks</h2>
<div class="tasks" id="incomplete_tasks">
  <form class="edit_task" id="edit_task_4" action="/tasks/4" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="patch" /><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="+1mGLeoE51+7p+uDVQmI2QCxwvbmuNRw4lnMEJbB25vekwOBavFs/Efo4X3AD5FMTE2EwJym4o462aUQjzda2w==" />
  <input name="task[complete]" type="hidden" value="0" /><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="task[complete]" id="task_complete" />
  <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Update" data-disable-with="Update" />
  <label for="task_complete">foo</label>
  <a data-confirm="Are you sure?" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/tasks/4">(remove)</a>
</form>
<form class="edit_task" id="edit_task_5" action="/tasks/5" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="patch" /><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="dnc364MuSvkRuVLLRBnEG6cfoABSeoui7Iq729wmWQRgAxizDoT2oetX5WDSoITSQIs6Bi4GoGrkEqJicU6lhg==" />
  <input name="task[complete]" type="hidden" value="0" /><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="task[complete]" id="task_complete" />
  <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Update" data-disable-with="Update" />
  <label for="task_complete">bar</label>
  <a data-confirm="Are you sure?" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/tasks/5">(remove)</a>
</form>
<form class="edit_task" id="edit_task_6" action="/tasks/6" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="patch" /><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="HW9YKsH9ETOugVJT0IkttgUwdjlUNL/MpXSjWagYJLG5fmjjZZWqInSEuQE2yhNmAOZkIFPeyd2leT3nia0g8g==" />
  <input name="task[complete]" type="hidden" value="0" /><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="task[complete]" id="task_complete" />
  <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Update" data-disable-with="Update" />
  <label for="task_complete">baz</label>
  <a data-confirm="Are you sure?" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/tasks/6">(remove)</a>
</form>

</div>

<h2>Comlpete Tasks</h2>
<div class="tasks" id="complete_tasks">

</div>

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have the code on github or a similar platform? I would like to check it out.

Comment: [bparanj/ckl](https://github.com/bparanj/ckl)

Comment: Can you give us a look at the raw html that is produced by this set of tasks? That will help us tell what is going on.

Comment: @TarynEast see edit :)

Comment: @mbigras I am unable to reproduce the weird behaviour you described. It works fine to me.

Comment: @ArunKumar what about when you `git checkout 1bb43bd`?

Comment: @mbigras I did checkout `1bb43bd` and it worked fine. Maybe it is a browser issue?

Comment: @ArunKumar weird...just tried it with Chrome, Safari, and Firefox and getting the same unexpected behavior. You tried toggling all the different tasks? It's the first task that gets toggled no matter when for me

Comment: Yeah, I am pretty sure. When I click on the third checkbox in the list, the third checkbox is the one responding.

Comment: @ArunKumar Ahhh right! don't click the actual checkbox, click the text instead!

Comment: Ok, so looking at the raw html I notice that every checkbox has the same html id: `id="task_complete"` That is where the issue stems from... I don't know why your browser is reacting to that by checking only the first checkbox with that id, but it is a given requirement in html that id's *must* be unique across the entire html page (and that behaviour is not guaranteed if you don't). So... now we know what the problem is... now you just need to figure out how to fix it. ;)

Comment: @TarynEast Can you please move your comment to an answer?

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem.... just points out what's causing the error, but sure.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so looking at the raw html I notice that every checkbox has the same html id:

```
id="task_complete"
```

That is where the issue stems from...

I don't know why your browser is reacting to that by checking only the first checkbox with that id, but it is a given requirement in html that id's must be unique across the entire html page (and that behaviour is not guaranteed if you don't).

So... now we know what the problem is... now you just need to figure out how to fix it. ;)

You can test this theory by manually passing in a unique id for each checkbox eg something like (note not bug-tested):

```
<%= f.check_box :complete, :id => "task_complete_#{task.id}" %>
```

Comment: So are you saying that clicking behavior was just some unintended side effect and the task label was never intended to be clickable?

Comment: Task-label could plausibly be clickable... but if so, it suffers the same problem... when you click it... the browser will assume that there is one-and-one-only element with the id `task_complete` and will look through the page for the first instance of that id... which is the first in the list - and that's the one that will get `checked`. So in order to make your code work, you'll need to make sure that the ids are unique and the labels match the ids